# Android Device Monitor in Android Studio, can't access file explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following a tutorial online and the user went to `Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor` and they got this

[image]

Whereas when I do the exact same thing, it opens a tab along the bottom which looks like this...

[image]

As you can agree, these seem vastly different. I am using my android phone, which I have enabled developer mode on and my app runs fine but I cannot seem to get to the file explorer to view the database. Any idea why this is the case and how I can access the file explorer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @CaptJak https://youtu.be/p8TaTgr4uKM?t=547

Comment: Version of android studio and OS?

Comment: @CaptJak 1.5.1 and Windows 8.1

Comment: It's there. Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor (not Android Monitor, which is what is in *your* screenshot).

Comment: It is there > http://i.imgur.com/jU9tZX8.png

But, it just opens that tab...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108344/discussion-between-captjak-and-mcclosa).